# ASP.NET/IIS incorrectly buffers when <%@ Page Buffer="false" /> when accessed via 127.0.0.1 but not via localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis

ASP.NET/IIS incorrectly buffers a long-running page despite <%@ Page Buffer="false" /> when accessed via 127.0.0.1. This does not happen when the same page is accessed via localhost or via the hostname. Unbuffered behaviour is what is expected.

In IIS Manager / Site/ ASP / Enable Buffering [BufferingOn] is set to false.

The machine runs on a IPv4+ IPv6 network, so I suspect it is related to that, but I don't know what configuration needs to be changed to make this work correctly over IPv4 addresses.

So

`http://localhost:807/   --> doesn't buffer (correct)

http://mymachinename:807/   --> doesn't buffer (correct)

http://127.0.0.1:807/   --> buffers  (incorrect)

http://10.0.0.1:807/   --> buffers  (incorrect)  (machine ip)`